# Chrome updates in maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

What is the conventional way to handle chrome updates(versions) in your UI automation framework (Maven, Java)?

I have tried to update dependency in pom.xml file. It works. Is there any other options? Can i continue to use older version of Chrome in test execution. How to implement it in singelton design pattern?

Comment: "How to implement it in singleton design pattern?" Why are you asking for design patterns for code while asking a question on a declarative build system like Maven?